# Prestashop for large business

Tags: prestashop

I am in process of picking new adequate ecommerce platform for a company.

Their present eshop has average 130 visits per day, average 30 orders per day, about 100000 product in database from which 30000 are active and 3 - 5 operators which handles the orders.

Shop will be synced and managed in company erp system (now Microsoft Dynamics NAV, in near future something else).

Could you please tell me if Prestashop is good solution or do you recommend something better?

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience, bigger stores do not have problems with Prestashop.

But if your product features are high, you'll probably be having trouble with the PrestaShop Layer Search module.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer it this way, I've seen sites 3 or 4 times bigger than that and they work without major problems with PrestaShop. The problem here will not be your eCommerce software, but rather your server, the resources that it will have and how well its configured.